# Jetpack Compose lazyrow considerably slower than a recyclerView on xml

Tags: android, optimization, android-jetpack-compose, lazy-loading, android-xml

I'm developing an app for a very limited hardware and decided to use jetpack compose.

The problem arises when I need to display a list of cards and the lazyrow used for it gets extremely laggy. For comparison, I picked up a sample project with a recyclerView and used it to display roughly the same list of cards and the scrolling is as smooth as can be. Is jetpack compose inherently slower than xml view or am I doing something wrong?

Compose code (I can't exactly share my code, but the card composable is just a card with some images, icons and text):

```
@Composable
fun mainComposable(){
    ...
    cardList = remember{ arrayListOf(...) }
    lazyList(cardList)
    ...
}

@Composable
fun lazyList(
cardList: List<CardContent>,
){
    LazyRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 32.dp)

        ) {
        items(
            items = cardList,
            key = { it.id }) { item ->
            CardComposable(
                content = item
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I've already spent some time searching so I found a lot of optimizations, like running in release mode, setting minifyEnabled and shrinkResources to true on build.gradle and android.enableR8.fullMode to true in gradle.properties, using keys on the LazyRow, etc. They helped, but the scrolling is still fundamentally slower than an equivalent xml view app with recyclerView.

Edit: Added CardComposable code

```
@Composable
fun CardComposable(
    content: Content,
) {

    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        elevation = 1.dp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(216.dp)
            .height(308.dp)
    ) {
        Column {

            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = content.image),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(216.dp)
                        .height(164.dp)
                )
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.button_background),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(40.dp)
                            .height(40.dp)
                    )
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.button),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(16.dp)
                            .height(16.dp),
                        tint = GenericRedColor
                    )
                }
            }

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 16.dp)
            ) {

                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Text(
                        text = content.Name,
                        maxLines = 2,
                        color = GenericBlackColor,
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(134.dp)
                            .padding(top = 16.dp)
                    )

                    Box(
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 8.dp)
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.square_button),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(32.dp)
                                .height(32.dp),
                            tint = GenericRedColor
                        )
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.button_icon),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(16.dp)
                                .height(16.dp),
                            tint = GenericWhiteColor
                        )
                    }
                }

                Text(
                    text = content.contentType,
                    color = GenericLightGrayColor2,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)
                )

                Row(
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(26.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 24.dp)
                ) {

                    val iconModifier = Modifier
                        .padding(end = 4.dp)
                        .width(12.dp)
                        .height(12.dp)

                    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.icon_1),
                            modifier = iconModifier,
                            tint = GenericLightGrayColor2
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = content.text_1,
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            color = GenericLightGrayColor2
                        )
           
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.icon_2),
                            modifier = iconModifier,
                            tint = GenericLightGrayColor2
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = content.text2,
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            color = GenericLightGrayColor2
                        )
      
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.icon_3),
                            modifier = iconModifier,
                            tint = GenericLightGrayColor2
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = content.text3,
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            color = GenericLightGrayColor2
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably there is too much code running on the main thread, can you share the card content and the function the builds them?

Comment: @zjmo I added a changed version of the CardComposable, without sensitive information. But it is basically what I put there.

Comment: cannot spot any particular problem, but i think you got it, check the "content" object, how are you loading the image? very f all coroutines are running on the right dispatcher, even if you have flows, make sure of the same. I really doubt that a horizonal row can be so heavy...but now i see you said very limited hardware, it is kind of generic but in that case i would seariously trying to reduce all the size of the images and minimaze the number of objects your are showing in each screen, expanding the navigation graph and reducing the amount of active memory for each ui state

Comment: try to minimize the recomposition, there are many guides about it, just search compose optimization

Comment: I'm loading the images in the simplest way I know, from the drawable folder (for now) and I've already reduced the images as much as I can. I'm going with the other answer that is to put an AndroidView and use RecyclerView, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jetpack Compose is a separate library and is not included in the Android Operating System. Hence the code from the library should be **Just In Time (JIT)** compiled on the first run. This makes it inherently slower than Android View based code which is **Ahead Of Time compiled(AOT)** and binaries are stored inside the OS on the device.

This design decision of making Jetpack Compose as a standalone library has its advantages too. It makes it easier to update and use different versions of the library irrespective of the Android OS version, and  enables backwards compatibility between compose and android versions.

In iOS, Swift takes the other approach and the Swift binaries are Ahead Of Time compiled and included in the OS. This is one of the main reasons other than Apple's laziness that prevents backwards compatibility in iOS.

Regarding the performance differences between RecyclerView and LazyLists, LazyLists are considerably less performant than RecyclerView. This has multiple reasons. I think it's mainly because Compose is a newer library and is constantly improving. The performance of earlier versions of LazyLists were considerably worse. Performance would be further improved in the upcoming compose versions.

For the time being, Since Jetpack Compose has interoperability with Android View based code, you can use RecyclerView in Compose with minimal performance overhead. Using `AndroidView()` function in Jetpack Compose.

```
@Composable
fun MyView(data: State<List<Item>>) {
    //This function enables Compose to interop with View based code.
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            RecyclerView(context).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                adapter = ItemListAdapter().also { it.submitList().value }
            }
        },
        update = { recyclerView ->
            //Callback that runs on each recomposition.
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I managed to use the recyclerView and it's surprisingly smooth, thanks. I've run into another problem though:
I'm using pointerInput with detectHorizontalGestures on the whole screen to detect drag gestures and swipe between pages and this is taking precedence to the RecyclerView (something that doesn't happen with the lazyRow). Do you have any idea how to make the AndroidView have precedence on the dragGesture?

Comment: I've managed to make it work adding the horizontalScroll modifier to the androidView, but that completely tanks the app performance

Comment: Try using the Jetpack Compose Navigation Library for moving between Screens. You can also set custom animations for screen transitions.

Comment: If that doesn't fit your requirements, you can also use Pager Layouts from Google's Jetpack Compose Accompanist library.